# Can't seem to get unplated in UWP

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Update: 20 May - Just want to make it clear what I'm looking for, this photo shows what I mean when I mention the "AppList"  https://www.flickr.com/photos/143242909@N03/27002577792/in/dateposted-public/

I still can't figure it out.

---

I've been messing around with the UWP in Visual Studio 15 with Windows 10 and trying to learn how to get the package manifest to display the best possible logos and icons for an application.

But I've hit a snag.

I want to use unplated icons for the taskbar and start menu.  I created icons at every unplated size available, and the designer keeps placing one in the 44x44 slot. I've tried using it, renaming it, editing the package manifest in notepad...

The taskbar icon comes out fine and unplated...  the one in the Apps List (Start Menu) insists on being plated.

When I try editing in notepad and renaming the 44 to:
`Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-44_altform-unplated.png`

I get this error:

> Image path contains one or more MRT qualifiers, which is not supported.  Remove the 'AlternateForm' qualifier with value unplated and retry the operation.

Has anyone succeeded in getting an unplated icon to show up in the Applications List?

Comment: @Ajean, thank you for fixing the formatting on my post!

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets)

> Target-size list assets without plate
>
> These are assets that don't get plated or scaled by the system.
>   File name format: *AppList.targetsize-*_altform-unplated.PNG
>   Impacted apps: Every UWP app
>   Uses:
>   Taskbar and taskbar thumbnail (desktop) Taskbar
>   jumplist Task view ALT+TAB

Comment: I've tried it, but I still seem to have no luck getting it to work.

Tried renaming it both ways with {myappname}.targetsize-44_altform-unplated.png

and 

{myappname}AppList.targetsize-44_altform-unplated.png

Comment: As I see now your file name is correct except that targetsize-44 is missing in list. But you can use targetsize-40

Comment: Tried using 40x40 icon as you suggested, using all three variations of the filename with "40" in the name as the size.  No good... still doesn't work.

Comment: Strange, but I don't get any exception with file Square44x44Logo.targetsize-40_altform-unplated.png in Assets. What UWP target platform version are you using? (I have tried with 10240)

Comment: I'm on 10586, targeting for same...  I don't get an exception, it shows an error icon in the Package Manifest UI.  But I suspect it's not a Windows build issue.

Alexej, can you try to see if you can get an unplated icon to show up in your AppList in one of your apps?  Maybe if you can get it to work in one of yours, we can figure out why it's not working in mine.

Comment: it's works on my pc http://s32.postimg.org/4l69ndkz9/image.png and http://s32.postimg.org/nl686u99x/image.png Try to check images size

Comment: Yes, on the taskbar I can get it to show up unplated:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/143242909@N03/26493094393/in/dateposted-public/

But in the AppList on the Windows 10 Start Menu, it shows up plated (with the black border) regardless of what I do:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/143242909@N03/27002577792/in/dateposted-public/